# Cannot save file on iOS using Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using the file_picker plugin to provide me with a path where to store my result which is an Uint8List. Here is (a simple version) of my code:

```
//this is way bigger in reality
Uint8List result = Uint8List.fromList([1,2,3,4]);

String? path = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath(dialogTitle: "Pick destination");
if (path == null) return;

io.File encryptedFile = io.File("$path/myfilename.myExtension");
encryptedFile.writeAsBytes(result);
```

I've got the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: 
Cannot open file, path = '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/
7FEABE47-9622-41B8-91F7-A4147840C272/File Provider Storage/Encrypted/
Gescanntes Dokument.pdf.aescryptor' 
(OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
#1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you gave permissions?

Comment: Yes, just like it is said in file_picker documentation. If I need to give more permissions, how do I do this?